# Converting DateTime to Epoch milliseconds using Cypher in Neo4J

Tags: date, datetime, neo4j, cypher

I'm running a query using Cypher in Neo4J where I have to compare a `createdAt` property of a node against a given time unit in Epoch milliseconds. This `createdAt` property is a `string` in the `DateTime` format, which is defined as -

> ### **DateTime**
>
> date with a precision of miliseconds, encoded as a string with the following format: yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss.sss+0000, where yyyy is
>   a four-digit integer representing the year, the year, mm is a
>   two-digit integer representing the month and dd is a two-digit integer
>   representing the day, HH is a two-digit integer representing the hour,
>   MM is a two digit integer representing the minute and ss.sss is a five
>   digit fixed point real number representing the seconds up to
>   milisecond precision. Finally, the +0000 of the end represents the
>   timezone, which in this case is always GMT.

Here are a couple of values of this property - `2011-03-21T19:32:38.295+0000`, `2012-03-09T17:59:05.367+0000`.

I came across the [Temporal Values documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/temporal/) on Neo4j, but couldn't find a way to perform the conversion.

When I execute some of the given examples, like this -

> `RETURN datetime('2015-06-24T12:50:35.556+0100') AS theDateTime`

I get the error -

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'datetime' (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporal functions were added in neo4j version 3.4.0, and I have verified that your query works in that version.

Make sure you are using an appropriately recent version of neo4j.

Comment: Thank You! I was on the 3.3.0 version earlier, and the docs didn't mention anything about this feature not being present earlier.