# Neo4j Cypher - Changing datetime to epoch timestamp

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to convert a `datetime()` (e.g. `"2019-10-19T20:57:52.541000000Z"`)

to the same format that would be output by `timestamp()` (e.g. `1571518672541`)

I understand to convert it one way you would use something like the following;

`RETURN datetime({epochmillis:1571518672541}) AS theDate`

However I would actually like to do the reverse of this and am really struggling with understanding the Neo4j documentation.

I found this question where the title is labelled for what I believe I want, but the output seems to be wrong so just found that even more confusing;
[Converting DateTime to Epoch milliseconds using Cypher in Neo4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168792/converting-datetime-to-epoch-milliseconds-using-cypher-in-neo4j)

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporal instants (like `DateTime`) support many [properties](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants), and among them are `epochMillis` (and `epochSeconds`).

For example:

```
RETURN datetime({epochMillis: 1571518672541}).epochMillis
```

will return `1571518672541`.